# Force javascript calcuation in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: javascript, itext

Simplifying the question. because i don;t want to confuse.

In my pdf there are 3 field to perform add operation.

In two field I enter a number and third field should show the addition of that two number.
To make the addition I have return java script.

Now using itextsharp we all know we can set the field value but third field is not getting calculated until i open the pdf and do some stuff of click and tab of fields.

I have read certain place itextsharp don;t support to make force calculation/execution of java script from code.

Can any one tell me does any support is added to handle such scenario or is there any work around to force the java script to execute.

OR any other way to handle such things.

Comment: iTextSharp does not *execute* JavaScript. It merely allows you to *manipulate* the JavaScript in a PDF. Thus, the only thing you might try is to add some global JavaScript executed upon opening the document which triggers the calculation script.

Comment: For your "OR any other way to handle such things", can you just perform your calculation and set the field by hand using iTextSharp?

Comment: I already have pdf's which have good amount fields which contain javascript for certain calculation like 2 + 2 = 4 where 2 is input value n sume handled in javascript.                                                                                        Now I want execute this javascript to make sum from itextsharp or any other tool .  Simply is that possible to execute java code in pdf without opening pdf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTextSharp: Javascript in PDF not firing when filled in in vb.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014807/itextsharp-javascript-in-pdf-not-firing-when-filled-in-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

To execute generic Javascript code, a PDF processor would need to completely emulate the Adobe Reader Javascript object model. As far as I know there is no PDF library around that does so, especially no freely available or low prized one.

iText(Sharp) in particular does not execute any Javascript as a result of its manipulating PDFs.

It might be feasible to support a subset of the Adobe Reader Javascript capabilities which suffices to support calculated fields. Any PDF library project surely would be happy to integrate such a thing as an optional feature.