# iTextSharp: Javascript in PDF not firing when filled in in vb.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, pdf, adobe, itext

I use iTextSharp to fill in the PDF server-sided and return it so that the client can download it.

Here's the [link](http://download.belastingdienst.nl/belastingdienst/docs/verzoek_berekening_beslagvrije_voet_ov2111z7fol.pdf) to the pdf.

The problem is number 1. You can only fill in the PDF if you have one of the boxes checked. If none is checked, everything will be "empty". The content isn't removed and returns once a box has been checked.

Everything gets populated, but there is a problem. The checkbox gets checked, but the Javascript behind it doesn't fire. Any solutions?

Comment: iText doesn't evaluate the JavaScript in a PDF form, hence the behavior you are seeing is normal. We have no immediate intentions to implement firing JavaScript in AcroForm forms. If you are an iText customer, you can vote to get this on the technical roadmap. If you aren't an iText customer, you can implement this yourself and contribute your code back to the community along with the rest of the code you're writing.

Comment: @ChunTang Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: @mkl I recently found out that 'fields.SetFieldProperty(field.Key, "flags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT, Nothing)' works for me. Seems I misinterpreted that it was javascript, and it was more UI based.

Comment: Yes, flags and field flags are *not* JavaScript stuff, just some bit fields attached to fields, and their values influence PDF viewer behavior directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use iText(Sharp) to fill in forms, Javascript events wont be triggered.

Many events make no sense, no focus is gained or lost, no keys are typed, iText(Sharp) directly changes the PDF objects, it does not emulate a person filling in the forms.

Furthermore, iText(Sharp) does not include a JavaScript execution environment with an Adobe Reader object model to begin with.

---

> Any solutions?

While I wrote the above, @Bruno already explained in a comment that you can either

- vote to get some kind of Javascript support on the roadmap of iText if you are a paying iText customer;
- wait and hope other iText users who are iText customers vote that onto the roadmap if you are not a paying iText customer;
- implement such a Javascript support into iText yourself; it's open source after all; but be aware of the viral iText license; or
- analyze the Javascript in your PDF and hard code analogous operations into your code

Comment: It should actually be sufficient to add a PageOpen script on the first page with which the document opens: this.calculateNow() ; (assuming that the fields are actually filled).

Comment: At first glance there were non-trivial Javascript scriplets coupled with the focus. I'm not sure a simple `calculateNow` would result in the expected state. But worth a try indeed!

Comment: Yikes… This form may be in need of a serious analysis and if needed a makeover. It may, OTOH, be that this "non-trivial JavaScript scriptlets" have no influence on the actual calculations, but are more UI-related. If this is the case, they can be mostly disregarded when the form is filled server-side.